# Функция wp_add_inline_style без type='text/css'

Tags: php, wordpress

Функция `wp_add_inline_style` выводит блок CSS стилей с атрибутом `type='text/css'`, возможно ли как-то в WP вывести стили без `type='text/css'`?

```
wp_add_inline_style( 'my_pl', $inline_css );
```

Comment: Зачем это, можно узнать?

Comment: @KAGGDesign type='text/css' невалидный, клиент хочет что-бы валидатор не ругался.

Comment: С какого бодуна он стал невалидным? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp

Comment: Если очень хочется, делать надо через https://wp-kama.ru/hook/style_loader_tag

Comment: @KAGGDesign хз, но сейчас он невалидный.

Comment: Невалидно не значения свойства type, но само свойство - нет такого у элемента style: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-style-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без бубна [никак](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php#L297).

Можно обойтись без *wp_add_inline_style*:

```
add_action(
    'wp_head',
    function () {
        echo '<style>.entry .entry-title a {color: blue}</style>';
    },
    999
);
```